# How do I list all documents in a collection but show a single property?

Tags: mongodb

How do I list all documents in a collection but show a single property through a console window?

```
//Trying to just show name property
db.mycollection.find({name});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**`find`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html) mongo command accepts 2 parameters:

```
db.collection.find(query, projection)
```

**query (Optional):**

> Specifies selection filter using query operators. To return all
>   documents in a collection, omit this parameter or pass an empty
>   document ({}).

**[projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html#find-projection) (Optional):**

> Specifies the fields to return in the documents that match the query
>   filter. To return all fields in the matching documents, omit this
>   parameter. For details, see Projection.

In your scenario you have to use the projection parameter to specify which fields to be returned as so:

```
db.mycollection.find({}, {_id: 0, name: 1});
```

Since you do not care about providing criteria you can just leave that as empty object.

The `{_id: 0, name: 1}` means that you do not want the default `_id` field included in the results and only care/want the `name` field.

Comment: "jinx" 8 second difference when I answered but you gave extra insight

Answer (score 3):

You can set your showing propertys this way:

```
db.mycollection.find({name:name}, {_id:0, name:1});
```

It will only show the name and hide the _id

Answer (score 0):

db.mycollection.find({}, { _id:0, name: 1})